# grep only certain directories with dynamic names

Tags: grep

I have a folder list that looks like:

```
/customer/<dynamic value>/<job id>/temp_data/processing/bko
```

My current `grep` looks like:

```
find . path "*/temp_data/processing/bko/*/out/*" -exec grep -R "NOT FOUND" --include=\*.ind /dev/null {} +
```

I am pulling back desired results from desired locations that look like:

```
./<dynamic value>/<job id>/temp_data/processing/bko/<filename>/out/<filename>.ind
```

But then I am also getting results from locations like:

```
/<dynamic value>/<job id>/temp_data/processing/<filename>.ind
```

Comment: is the missing `-` in front of `path` intentional?

Comment: That's exactly what it was. Thank you. Feel free to create an answer for the benefit of others.

Comment: Okay, see my answer. What is the purpose of `/dev/null` in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `-` in front of `path`, it must be `-path`.

Also, you may want to add `-type f` option to `find` and remove the `-R` option from `grep` (the `find` command cares about recursion).

```
find . -path "*/temp_data/processing/bko/*/out/*" -type f \
  -exec grep "NOT FOUND" --include=\*.ind {} +
```